# Generating Graphs like plantuml or mermaid from markdown?

Tags: graph, markdown, plantuml, generate, mermaid

[image]
[image]

I want to create graphs like this, as best in the style we see in the pictures. Every Node should contain a link to another page.

How can I achieve this? Esp. with the nice style.

I have tried to do this with plantuml and mermaid but didn't get good results.

Does anyone have a link to the tool used in the images?
Or does anyone know a way how to achieve this?

Comment: Hello! I suspect it was not a program that did the layout, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The image is open source https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap/blob/master/public/images/system-design.png perhaps the repo owner can tell you

Comment: Wow - that is a big diagram :)  I would argue that this was probably done in a visual editing tool like Visio though.

Being able to have a node in mermaid that links to a separate diagram is something that I have been looking into though